# RegionMeasure is not accurate

Tags: regions, geometry

I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0, on a Mac.

I have a list of 51 non-intersecting balls of radius 1. The total volume is easily computed exactly, $51\times 4\pi/3 \approx 213.6283004441$.

Now suppose I put the centers of the spheres in a file (attached, `sphere.txt`), and then I do this:

```
spheres = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "/spheres.txt", "Table"]
RegionMeasure[RegionUnion @@ (Ball[#, 1] & /@ spheres)]
```

The answer I get `202.068`, has an error of 6%.

I need to compute region volumes of more complicated region unions that might overlap, but this result is discouraging. Is there a way to improve this result?

The example file `spheres.txt` can be downloaded from [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/2RgJLmNr). Note that the balls are *touching* at the surface, but the volume of the intersection between any pair is zero.

Comment: Are you sure that these balls are disjoint? `RegionDisjoint @@ (Ball[#, 1] & /@ spheres)` says `False`.  That answer *could* be incorrect, but have you verified it?

Comment: Actually, they *are* disjoint (they are just touching).  `Union@Flatten@DistanceMatrix[spheres]` starts with `{0., 2., ...}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs The spheres are touching, I should have warned about that. But I confirmed by computing the volume of the intersections between every pair of balls, and that is zero.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should be possible to do it in several ways: 1. `Method -> {"NIntegrate", PrecisionGoal -> ...}` (doesn't work)  2. `NIntegrate[1, x \[Element] region, PrecisionGoal -> ...]` (doesn't work well) 3. `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[..., MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]`, then `RegionMeasure` (works, but very slow).    Good question, I don't have a good answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There was a bad value at the very end (only one value instead of three on a line). Did you remove it?

Comment: @Szabolcs Just figured that out...

Comment: @Szabolcs I had fixed that, but someone edited the question and posted a new pastebin link using the old link. Now I fixed it again.

Comment: It appears that as soon as you have 9 or more spheres of which at least two intersect, even at a single point, then the error suddenly goes up.  Minimal example: `RegionMeasure[RegionUnion @@ (Ball[#, 1] & /@ spheres[[#]])] - Length[#] 4 Pi/3 &@{1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17}`.  (Only spheres 1 and 2 touch; the others are disjoint.)

Comment: `RegionMeasure` is (afaik) based on `DiscretizeRegion`, which I've found to be problematic in many ways. One alternative might be with `Volume`, which seems to know about the exact volume of a sphere (and about sphere intersections). Specifically, `Volume[Ball[spheres[[1 ;; k]], ConstantArray[1, k]]]` manages to compute the area with an error of about `10^-7`, but only up to `k = 9` at which point it breaks. (Possibly related to @MichaelE2's comment?)

Comment: Now I cannot find an example of 9 spheres that are computed accurately, whether or not they touch.  I'm pretty sure a random sample did work once, but I don't know which spheres were chosen.

Comment: FWIW, in MMA 10.4 the result is 211.133, i.e., a relative error of around 1%.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Damn regressions...

Comment: @becko `Volume` returns different value than `RegionMeasure` and both are incorrect. Have you reported this?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I have not reported this. I might tomorrow, but go ahead if you want to do it first.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

balls = Flatten[
   Table[Ball[{x, y, z}], {x, 0, 20, 2}, {y, 0, 20, 2}, {z, 0, 20, 
     2}], 2];

Length[balls]

(*  1331  *)

ballsRgn = RegionUnion[balls];

Volume[ballsRgn] == Total[Volume /@ balls] == 
 Length[balls]*Volume[Ball[]]== 1331*4 Pi/3

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Curious that this works fine. Any idea why my example fails?

Comment: @becko - I was unable to access your data so I cannot know why it has problems.

Comment: It's on pastebin, https://pastebin.com/raw/2RgJLmNr.

Comment: @becko - rationalize your data and you can see that there is overlap between some of the balls. `Length[Select[
  Norm /@ (Subtract @@@ 
     Subsets[spheres // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {2}]), # < 2 &]]`

Comment: No, there isn't. Try `Union@N@DistanceMatrix@Rationalize[spheres, 0]`, you will see the distances between the centers are all `>= 2`.

Comment: @becko - Using `N@` employs machine precision and precludes you from seeing the numbers that are slightly less than 2. Use `N[#,20]&@` and you will see the 15 numbers slightly less than 2

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's enough to justify a volume error of 11 units.

Comment: @becko - the comments under your question indicated that there is a problem if the spheres overlap. The follow-on was to convince you that there was overlap.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were arguing that the overlap could have a volume of 11, making Mathematica's result correct. I see now this is not what you were saying, sorry. I generated these spheres using a random process avoiding overlap. Some tiny residual overlap is to be expected, due to machine arithmetic error.